# EC2 EBS partitions went into in-accessible state and the LVM mount point went to inactive state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

EC2 EBS partitions went into in-accessible state and the LVM mount point went to inactive state.

Any suggestion ?

We have have started the new snapshot of ebs volume not sure this is gonna help .
Any comments or suggestion ?
According to our server team ,snapshot created will be in error state only ?

Answer (score 0):

created a snapshot of ebs volume and mounted it